# Oracle Apex - Save info on two rows while updating one row only

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I'm using an Interactive Grid as a way for the user to make easy updates on a table. The issue is that in some occasions I have 2 or more rows per Product, as such:

[image]

create table example (
id number,
product varchar2(100),
status  varchar2(100)
)

(ID column as Primary Key)

The idea is for the user to update Product Status using one row and have all rows for that same product updated.
For example, if the user updates Status on one row of Product A to 'Excellent' I would like for the two rows under Product A to be updated to excellent.
Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: What happens if the user updates row 1 to Excellent and row 2 to Fair? It sounds like your table is not completely denormalized.

Comment: Yeah, perhaps that wasn't a good example.
My original table has one row per Customer, however, I need to add installed product information for each one. Thus, multiplying rows (if Customer has 2 products installed, we'll have 2 rows, and so on). There are additional columns that the user will update manually via Interactive Grid and it would be ideal for the table to update all 2 rows (or 3 or 4) while the user only updates a single one.